# html2canvas not allowing to show a vector type google map

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, html2canvas

I'm trying to display a vector type google map (it's mandatory that it be this way due to certain features that I can only get with the vector type).

The problem is that apparently the html2canvas library seems to work well with **raster type maps**, I've seen several posts where they make it work with raster types and they worked perfectly for me.
However, I have not been able to find a way to make it work with a vector type map.
The apparent reason why it doesn't work with vector type maps is because it is unable to detect the CSS that is in maps of this type.

An image says more than a thousand words so I will show you image by image:

**FIRST IMAGE, THE PAGE**
[image: Image of the page]

As you can see, I need the map to be of the vector type to be able to draw these level 1 administrative sites of the country in different colors depending on a response from a service.

However, when I transfer said image to a pdf (since in the end what I need is to generate a pdf) I get all the content except the map:
[image: Imagen of the resultant PDF]

This is the result if I do it with a raster type map where I will not be able to use the drawing of level 1 administrative sites:

[image: Pdf of the raster map]

This is the code I'm currently using to get the results I showed above (I'm using Angular):

```js
@ViewChild('fullReport', { static: false }) fullReport!: ElementRef;

download() {
    const pdf = new jsPDF();

    html2canvas(this.fullReport.nativeElement, { useCORS: true }).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 210, 297);
      pdf.save('reporte.pdf');
    })

}
```

In the html file, I just have everything inside the "fullReport" div.

I already tried other libraries like "dom-to-image" but I couldn't even get them to work, I really don't know how I can solve this.

I appreciate any ideas or possible solutions.

**UPDATE**

This is the method that I use to render the map:

```
@ViewChild('divMap', { static: false }) divMap!: ElementRef;
mapa!: google.maps.Map;

googleMapsOptions(emergencies: any[]) {

const lat = 4.570868;
const lon = -74.297333;

const options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
  zoom: 4.5,
  mapId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  draggable: false,
  scrollwheel: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
};

this.mapa = new google.maps.Map(
  this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.divMap.nativeElement),
  options
);

const featureLayer = this.mapa.getFeatureLayer(google.maps.FeatureType.ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1)

function getFeatureStyleOptions(fillColor: string): google.maps.FeatureStyleOptions {
  return {
    strokeColor: fillColor,
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3.0,
    fillColor: fillColor,
    fillOpacity: 1
  };
}

const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

let placeIds: any = [];
let seccionalesNames: any = [];

emergencies.forEach((emergency) => {
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: `${emergency.latitud}, ${emergency.longitud}`,
  })
    .then(({ results }) => {
      if (results[0]) {
        results.map((result) => {
          if (result.types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
            placeIds.push(result.place_id);
            seccionalesNames.push(emergency.descripcion)
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.log("No results found");
      }
    })
    .finally(() => {
      //@ts-ignore
      featureLayer.style = (options: { feature: { placeId: string; }; }) => {
        const index = placeIds.indexOf(options.feature.placeId);
        if (index !== -1) {
          return getFeatureStyleOptions(this.getColorsByDepartamento(cleanString(seccionalesNames[index])));
        }
      }
    })

  emergency.color = this.getColorsByDepartamento(cleanString(emergency.descripcion));
})

this.separatePositions(emergencies);

}
```

I use the official google geocoder service so that according to the latitudes and longitudes of a position that I give, it returns something called "placeId" which will allow google to later draw each of the administrative areas that I want to show in the map (this happens in the "finally" method).

Comment: Solve the problem you have with the tools that solve your problem: if bitmaps work but vectors don't, grab a library that renders a vector image as a bitmap, then use that.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any libraries that do this? I've been looking around for a few, but the only one I've found so far is "canvg" and this only works with SVG images, not Google Maps vector types.

Comment: And what _are_ google maps vector types? As in "how are you drawing these" because google maps are their own self-contained system, you don't just draw them on your own canvas.

Comment: Do you mean the method I update in the question?

Comment: Hello. Google Maps API will not work when you convert it to pdf because that will make it "static". The way you were loading the Map is a "dynamic" way of doing it. So it kinda removes the whole point of calling it dynamic map. But in the case that you use static map, I'd recommend that you read and review ToS with regards to saving Map tiles. https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=3.2.3%C2%A0Restrictions%20Against%20Misusing%20the%20Services